# Удаление определённой строки в файле

Tags: c#

Ситуация такая: У меня есть файл, в нем записанны строки. Я пытаюсь найти строку по её содержанию и её удалить. Но проблема в том, что не могу найти в интернете как её удалить. 
*То-есть работа этого метода должна быть следующей:*

Пользователь вводит логин, и по файлу идёт поиск, если находит, то он должен эту строку удалить.

Сам файл:

```
lol:9cdfb439c7876e703e307864c9167a15
you:91c366db3df8b21eeb76be5c250f1a40
kek:4cfdc2e157eefe6facb983b1d557b3a1
wewe:2a7d544ccb742bd155e55c796de8e511
```

Вот мой код:

```
public void DeleteUser()
{
    var log = EnterLogin();

    string path = ".htpasswd";

    string[] deluser = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.Default);
    foreach (string items in deluser)
    {
        if (items.Contains(log))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Текстовый формат — потоковый, в нём невозможно выбросить часть из середины.

Читайте файл построчно, пишите в выходной (другой!) файл только нужные строки, потом удаляйте исходный файл и перенесите новый файл в позицию старого.

---

Альтернативным методом было бы читать файл по байту, запоминать текущую позицию чтения и записи, складывать байты через декодер кодировки в строку, при приходе конца строки проверять её, возможно, менять позицию записи, и отбрасывать в конце хвост. Поверьте, вам этого не хочется.

Comment: Как вариант считать файл в память, затем произвести поиск\удаление необходимой строки в подгруженном буфере (например считывать по 4 кб). При этом естественно запоминать с какой - по какую строку исходного файла мы считали. Если в буфере есть искомая строка, то удалить ее из буфера - и записать буфер на место (можно даже не целиком фрагмент записывать, а непосредственно изменения. А вообще для таких целей лучше использовать что нибудь подходящее - json/xml, тогда таких проблем бы не возникло.

Comment: @QuaternioNoir: Проблема в разборе кодировки. Например, для UTF-8 один символ может состоять из нескольких байт и пересекать границу четырёхкилобайтного буфера.

Answer (score 2):

Если дорабатывать ваш код, то надо сделать следующее:

```
public void DeleteUser()
{
    var log = EnterLogin();

    string path = ".htpasswd";

    string[] deluser = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.Default);
    deluser = deluser.Where(line => line != log);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, deluser, Encoding.Default);
}
```

Но в случае большого файла это будет более накладно, чем решение, предложенное VladD.

Answer (score 0):

Как как рабочий варианты, быть может кому ещё пригодится...

```
        public void DeleteUser()
        {
            var log = EnterLogin();
            string path = ".htpasswd";

            //var re = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.Default).Where(line => line != log);
            var re = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.Default).Where(line => line.Trim().IndexOf(log) == -1).ToArray();
            //var re = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.Default).Where(line => !line.Contains(log));
            File.WriteAllLines(path, re, Encoding.Default);
        }
```